# Custom Validity JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found tutorials which showing how to use javascript to set custom errors for a form's input fields. An example is as follows:

```
  document.getElementById('fname').setCustomValidity('Invalid');
```

However if i try to use jquery this does not seem to work. An example is as follows:

```
$('#fname').setCustomValidity('Invalid');
```

I prefer working with JQuery so can anyone tell me why this does not work and how i can possibly do the same in JQuery.

Comment: you cann add this function to jQueryprototype https://github.com/mikemaccana/jquery-html5-validity/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`setCustomValidity` is a *native* `javascript` method. Therefore, get a native `javascript object` and then call like

```
$('#fname').get(0).setCustomValidity('Invalid');
```

**Update**

> so why is it i dont have to put .get(0) when i always use JQuery. can you explain get(0) if possible?

The issue is not whether you are using `jQuery` or not. Rather the issue is you are trying to call a *native* **javascript** function that doesnt exist for `jQuery` objects. That is why using [**get()**](https://api.jquery.com/get/) will get you the native javascript `DOM` element that has access to the javascript function

Comment: so why is it i dont have to put .get(0) when i always use JQuery. can you explain get(0) if possible?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#fname')[0].setCustomValidity('Invalid');
```

Comment: @melvin, probably you are in a different case. The root of the matter is :
document.getElementById('fname') === $('#fname')[0]
and this is correct.